# Finding all divisors of integer besides the int itself and 1, and putting result into array

Tags: javascript

So I've gotten the function to return the divisors beside 1 and itself, but my loop is still adding empty array elements since it increments the `int` argument. Can someone see where I'm going wrong?

```
function divisors(integer) {

var result = [];
for(let i = 0; i < integer; i++) {
  if(i !== 1 && i !== integer && integer % i == 0) {
    result[i] = i;
  }
}

 return result;

};

console.log(divisors(12)); // returns array length of 7, 3 emtpy slot and 2, 3, 4, 6 ??
```

Comment: `result.push(i)`

Comment: @Pointy: That was quick, thank you! Can you explain why there are 3 empty elements in `result`? I don't understand ..

Comment: You use the divisor as the index into the array. If a number is divisible by 3 and not 2, you set `result[3]` to `3` but `result[2]` is never set to anything.

Comment: @Pointy: Hmm .. but in this case 12 is divisible by 2? Why wouldn't the array length be 10? Basically integer length beside one and 12?

Comment: Is 12 divisible by 5? 7? 9? Let alone 0 and 1, which you never set for any number. Arrays always start at 0.

Comment: @Pointy: So for example, because `2` passes the condition, when I set `result[2] = 2` does it automatically create two empty elements before that? If that makes sense. Sorry I am very new and trying to understand things as much as possible ..

Comment: Yes. Arrays always start at 0, so if you put something in slot 2 and not slot 0 or 1 then there will be two empty slots.

Comment: @Pointy: Ah so that's why the length is 7. Not sure why that was so hard to understand but you helped a lot, thank you sir!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add the elements using `push()`

```js
function divisors(integer) {

var result = [];
for(let i = 0; i < integer; i++) {
  if(i !== 1 && i !== integer && integer % i == 0) {
    result.push(i)
  }
}
 return result;
};

console.log(divisors(12));
```

A better way is to start the loop from `2`. And no need to check `i !== integer` because `i` will be always less than integer.

```js
function divisors(integer) {

var result = [];
for(let i = 2; i < integer; i++) {
  if(integer % i == 0) {
    result.push(i)
  }
}
 return result;
};

console.log(divisors(12));
```

A more cleaner on-liner will be using `filter()`

```js
const divisors = num => [...Array(num)]
                           .map((x,i) => i)
                           .filter(x => num % x === 0).slice(1)

console.log(divisors(12));
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Is there a cleaner way to check for all three conditions in the if statement?

Comment: Thank you, and lastly what is the best way to check if the argument is a prime number? I'm stuck on this last part, sorry

Comment: I love the `filter()` method! Very clean. Is this recommended in production?

Comment: @exception-io You can check the `length` of result is `0`  to check if the number is prime or not. However this is not the best way to check for primes. You should be looping upto `Math.sqrt(num)` if you want to check number is prime

Comment: And in the `.map()` x and i represent value and index respectively right?

Comment: @exception-io Yes exactly.

Comment: Really helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function divisors(integer) {
var divisors = [];
for (var i = 2; i < integer - 1; i++){
    if (integer % i === 0) divisors.push(i);
}
if (divisors.length === 0) return '' + integer + ' is prime';
return divisors;
```

}